# How to push changes to nested subtree?

Tags: git, github

I have 4 projects called

1. Math
2. Camera
3. CGOpenGL
4. OpenGLSandbox

**Math** is a *subtree* of **Camera**, **Camera** is a *subtree* of **CGOpenGL** and finally **CGOpenGL** is a *subtree* of **OpenGLSandbox**

While I was working in **OpenGLSandbox** I needed to make some changes to **Math**. After finishing the changes I did `git commit -am "bla bla"` and `git push` this was executed while being in the top directory, i.e. **OpenGLSandbox**

Important to say that I added three remotes

1. rmath points to repo of Math
2. ropengl points to repo of CGOpenGL
3. origin points to repo of OpenGLSandbox

After the previous commit to the main project (OpenGLSandbox) I wanted to push the changes from Math to its repository, so I tried `git subtree push --prefix=cgopengl/camera/math rmath master`

**a) the value of prefix is the path to the project that is the *subtree* we want to push?**

the previous command ended in the following error

```
 ! [rejected]        f60f3e788d6e8713a525cab0fe187f5f3b230b8e -> master (non-fast-forward) 
 error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/user123/Math.git' 
 hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind 
 hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. 
 hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

So I tried to do a pull with `git subtree pull --prefix=cgopengl/camera/math rmath master` and got the following error

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

**b) How can I push the changes made to Math from OpenGLSandbox project? I cannot find a way to overcome this. Where did I made a mistake?**